# Connect to an MS Access Database from SQL Management Studio

Tags: microsoft-access, sql-management-studio

I want to connect to an MS Access 2003 DB from SQL Management Studio 2005 so I can run queries on the Access DB from SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Add the MDB as a linked server

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx
2. Enable Ad Hoc Queries in SQL Server and use OpenDataSource

   http://riteshshah.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/read-xls-or-mdb-file-with-opendatasource-sql-server-2005/

   http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=266008

Comment: The link for adding the MDB as linked server is broken. I found [this one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-an-access-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017) as I'm trying the same with SSMS 2017

Answer (score 4):

You can also import the data into an existing database, via Tasks > Import Data. You can then select into which tables (new if desired) and how to map the columns